# React native native modules with swift getting exported method value as undefined?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, react-native-native-module

I am creating native module using [create-react-native-module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-native-module) with swift. After that I have followed react native official documentation for iOS setup. 
doc link:: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios

I have created create-react-native-module with example. I am just adding simple function with returning string "Hello World" inside my native module.

My 'CustomModule-Bridging-Header.h'::

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

My 'CustomModule.m'::

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(CustomModule, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(sampleMethod)

+ (BOOL) requiresMainQueueSetup {
  return YES;
}

@end
```

My 'CustomModule.swift':

```
import Foundation

@objc(CustomModule)
class CustomModule: NSObject {
  @objc(sampleMethod)
  func sampleMethod() -> String {
      return "Hello World"
  }
}
```

After making these changes to native module I have installed dependencies again inside example. Now my App.js is look like::

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import CustomModule from 'react-native-custom-module';

export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        message: '--'
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const msg = await CustomModule.sampleMethod();
        console.log('javascript calling msg::', msg);
        this.setState({
            message: msg
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>CustomModule example☆</Text>
                <Text>{this.state.message}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Here I am getting "msg" value as undefined. Please help!

Comment: Hi @Archana Sharma how did you sort out the "<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>" file not found issue when you first created the react-native-module from the command line. I am getting the above error. Could you please let me know ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use promise or callback to return value from the native function. Simply returning value does not work.

**Example using promise:**

CustomModule.swift

```
@objc
func sampleMethod(_ resolve: RCTPromiseResolveBlock, rejecter reject: RCTPromiseRejectBlock) {
  resolve("Hello World")
}
```

CustomModule.m

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(sampleMethod: (RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve rejecter: (RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

Comment: how to resolve a Query? You have mentioned resolve("Hello World"). What if I have a HKStatisticsQuery and I need to read this in my JS file. How can I resolve this???